# Python package with setuptools module has no attribute

Tags: python, pypi

I am following along with this pycon video on python packaging.

I have a directory:

- `mypackage/`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `mypackage.py`
- `readme.md`
- `setup.py`

The contents of `mypackage.py`:

```
class MyPackage():                                                                                                                                                                            
    '''
    My Damn Package
    '''
    def spam(self):
        return "eggs"
```

The contents of `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools                                                                                                                                                                             

setuptools.setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='My first package',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

Now I create a virtual env and install the package with:

```
pip install -e .
```

Now I do:

```
python
>>> import mypackage
>>> mypackage.MyPackage().spam()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'mypackage' has no attribute 'MyPackage'
```

Why is this not working as per the guy's tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `import mypackage` you import only `mypackage/__init__.py`. To get to `MyPackage` you need `mypackage/mypackage.py`:

```
from mypackage import mypackage
```

Comment: How can you prevent this? It's inconvenient to have to write this, and if you just `import mypackage` you then need to do `mypackage.mypackage.MyPackage()`. How can I make it so that `import mypackage` imports `mypackage.py`, not just `__init__.py`? I tried putting `import mypackage` inside of `__init__.py` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Use relative import: `import .mypackage` in `__init__.py` imports `mypackage.py`. Or even `from .mypackage import MyPackage`.

Comment: That actually threw a `SyntaxError` (which I found weird, because I also thought it should work). Anyway, the solution I ended up going with was to have `from mypackage.mypackage import *` inside `__init__.py`. Since `mypackage` is the directory containing `mypackage.py`, when typing `import mypackage`, `__init__.py` is called, which accesses the actual main code in `mypackage.py` and imports everything from it. After this, `MyPackage` can be accessed by simply writing `mypackage.MyPackage`. Also, `from mypackage import *` will import `MyPackage` directly, so I can use `MyPackage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `from .mypackage import *` inside the `init.py` file.