# Setuptools & Python Packaging

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899892/python-package-with-setuptools-module-has-no-attribute) but it does not fit 100% to mine.

I have this project layout:

```
src/  
└── mypackage/  
    ├── __init__.py     (empty)
    ├── a.py  
    └── mysubpackage1/  
        ├── __init__.py (empty)  
        └── b.py
```

As stated in the setuptools documentation, setuptools should be able to find my scripts without any modification since I use the src-layout. But this was not working, so I placed the following in my pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["*"]
```

After installing the package I can now import mypackage, but when I want to use the a.py script it states that the mypackage has no attribute a.

```
import mypackage

mypackage.a() <-- module 'mypackage' has no attribute 'a'
```

This would be my first problem, how can I create a package, so that when I import mypackage I can use the mypackage.a()?

Also I have to use:

```
from mpackage.mysubpackage1 import b
```

I would like to be able to import mypackage and then use it in the common way like:

```
import mypackage

mypackage.mysubpackage1.b.foo()
```

Setuptools docs do not help in any way, neither does the pyPA user guide.

The question above is close, I tried different approaches what I put in the init.py like:

```
from . import *

or 

from .mypackage import *
```

But nothing seems to work here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me like this has nothing to do with packaging, it is a question of imports. Maybe try `import mypackage.a`.

Comment: As stated, I would like not to import every single subpackage with an import statement. So I am asking how I can achieve that I only have to import the top level module and use the others as shown.

Comment: I would try with `from . import a` in `src/mypackage/__init__.py`.

Comment: Okay, this worked I was assuming that form . import * does the same, but I have to import all the scripts? Now I can use mypackage.a() but I am still not able to use mypackage.mysubpackage.b().

Comment: You are correct, this is more of an issue with how I import the packages with the init.py files.